# Swift fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, string, swift, fatal-error

I have textfield and i need to put inside session value and when i add gives me

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

error

My codes here

```
   @IBOutlet weak var discountField:UITextField!

 func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: MPGTextField_Swift, withSelection data: Dictionary<String,AnyObject>){

    let displayDiscount : AnyObject? = data["discount"]
    let addClientDiscount:String = (displayDiscount as? String)!
    prefs.setObject(addClientDiscount, forKey: "addClientDiscount")

    self.discountField.text = "\(addClientDiscount)" // THIS LINE GIVES ERROR

}
```

Also PROPERTLY Have ! in referencing Outlets

Thanks

Comment: show the declaration of discountField... you probably didn't instanciate it.

Comment: @Woodstock  updated codes.

Comment: Your IBOutlet is probably not properly connected in IB.

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper did you link your `discountField` to `xib` or `storyboard` properly?

Comment: exact as Eric D. said OR the view hierarchy isn't set, where are you calling this code?

Comment: @Breek YES PROPERTLY DID ! in referencing Outlets

Comment: @Woodstock im calling this code inside function

Comment: Function added , updated codes.

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper adding ! doesn't make it references properly, you have to check if there is a link between your `IB` and `discountField`. Btw, do you have multiple `textField`?

Comment: Try log `displayDiscount` first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle your line of error as follows:

```
self.discountField.text = data!["discount"] as? String ?? ""
```

If `data["discount"]` has a value, it will be assigned to the textfield, else an empty string will be used. But it will avoid the crash due to a `nil` value.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by many other guys, first check your IBOutlet connection.

If it's properly set, then put '?' after addClientDiscount as:

```
self.discountField.text = "\(addClientDiscount?)"
```

Because if this line

```
let displayDiscount : AnyObject? = data["discount"]
```

gives `nil` then crash may occur.
So to bypass that crash put '?'

**UPDATE**
As suggested by Eric D.
we can also do this:

```
if let displayDiscount = data["discount"] {
   let addClientDiscount = displayDiscount as! String
   prefs.setObject(addClientDiscount!, forKey: "addClientDiscount")

   self.discountField.text = "\(addClientDiscount!)"
}
```

Comment: @eric, Yes, I forgot to think of using 'if let'. Updated answer!